# Kindly suggest how to improve my question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I've gotten downvoted again as I'm learning what I think is quite difficult:

[How to wire a system for Nios 2 in Qsys?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/80835/how-to-arrange-my-connections-in-qsys)

I've had some problem and I might be asking similar question over and over but I'm really trying to make the project work and it is a system for FPGA. I think that the question can be improved since it was hastely put, should I make the title more specific and include more details?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please edit over all critical material for answering your question into your question. Putting a note, "here are some previous questions: 1 2 3 4 5" works, but it is pretty time consuming to have users go back and read 5 previous questions to find what your project is.